# Intellij 14.1.2 disable maven built-in ( use the M2_HOME by default like before )

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I've just upgraded to IDEA Intellij 14.1.2. A new feature for this version is that it comes with a built-in maven.

However, i have all my settings done in the maven version i have installed and set as M2_HOME, and i would like to continue to use that.

By default, each project now uses the built-in version instead of the one specified in M2_HOME.

Does anyone know how can i change the default back to use M2_HOME?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS: Preferences -> Build -> Execution -> Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven.

Windows: File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven

Look for "Maven home directory".
The dropdown should include at least the M2_HOME environment var.

[image: Preferences]

Comment: for windows it was a little hidden. On File tab, you have the big Settings, which actually only apply for the current project. But, after looking more carefully, it has also Other Settings, which have what i needed - the Default Settings